# appendChild usage, variable array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

trying to use appendChild to create a child element in a paragraph, I think I'm missing something fundamental here but I can't figure out what and not sure I'm using appendChild correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Accessing Variables from an Array</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var employees = [
    {
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
    "firstName":"Anna",
    "lastName":"Smith"
    },
    {
    "firstName":"Peter",
    "lastName":"Jones"
    }
];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
employees[0].firstName + " " + employees[0].lastName;


childtest=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=employees[1].firstName;
first = document.getElementById("demo");
first.appendChild(childtest);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a child of "demo" and take the second array of employees and make that the child element and output that underneath the first output.

Answer (score 1):

`childtest` is not a element here.

```
// Create a new empty <p> element.
var childtest = document.createElement('p');
// Set the innerHTML.
childtest.innerHTML = employees[1].firstname;
// Append that <p> element.
first.appendChild(childtest);
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you're not creating a new element and with `.innerHTML` you're just overwriting existing

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/21nk7mt2/)

```
var employees = [{
    "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
}];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = employees[0].firstName + " " + employees[0].lastName;



var newEl = document.createTextNode(employees[1].firstName);
first = document.getElementById("demo");
first.appendChild(newEl);
```

Comment: Quick question, why does the child element appear next to the parent element?  I thought that appendChild always made the element go below the parent Element, or is that incorrect?

Comment: @Snorlax because in this way we just added the text-element inside the existing div (in it's inner.HTML property); if you wanted to create a new element you'd have to append the text-element inside a newly created element and then append it - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/21nk7mt2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Katpoes got it right, just for clarification, this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>How to create a JavaScript object array.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var employees = [
    {
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
    "firstName":"Anna",
    "lastName":"Smith"
    },
    {
    "firstName":"Peter",
    "lastName":"Jones"
    }
];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
employees[0].firstName + " " + employees[0].lastName;
var childtest=document.createElement("p");
childtest.innerHTML = employees[1].firstName;
first = document.getElementById("demo");
first.appendChild(childtest);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```